# Google maps causing mixed content in header

Tags: ssl, google-maps

On two pages of a website I have a google maps coded via `iframe` like so:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=rest-of-link" width="100%" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

The problem is I'm getting mixed content warnings on those pages and they are caused by a `script` tag in the header which looks like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&#038;ver=4.7.5'></script>
```

I've looked through header file in the theme files, my page theme files and haven't found the `script` tag anywhere. There are no additional google maps plugins either.

Do you have any ideas where I could look for that or otherwise change the link to have `https` in url?

ps. I didn't create the website but I am maintaining it

Comment: Have you checked for wp_enqueue_script statements in your theme files? Or just searched for "maps.googleapis.com" or so? You might also be able to locate the script's origin using Chrome Inspector or similar tool.

Comment: A side-wide search for the string "4.7.5" will expose the culprit

Comment: @mayersdesign it helped thanks, and indeed, as CK MacLeod suggested it was wp_enque_script adding the link

Answer (score 1):

You can install HTTP/HTTPS Remover plugin to fix the issue. Generally, it works with all the plugins and themes.

You can download and install the plugin from https://wordpress.org/plugins/http-https-remover/